# Installing RVM in macOS (Catalina) errors

Tags: rvm, macos-catalina

I gave up.... trying to install RVM to MacOs Catalina I always get error. Any help? Running `brew tap --repair` shows nothing.

```
sdancer@192 ~ % \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   194  100   194    0     0    263      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   262
100 24532  100 24532    0     0  24003      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 24003
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/sdancer/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/sdancer/.mkshrc /Users/sdancer/.profile /Users/sdancer/.bashrc /Users/sdancer/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/sdancer/.profile /Users/sdancer/.bash_profile /Users/sdancer/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/sdancer/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12 (latest) (c) 2009-2020 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl@1.1.........There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install coreutils libyaml libksba readline zlib openssl@1.1',
please read /Users/sdancer/.rvm/log/1687864477_ruby-3.0.0/package_install_coreutils_libyaml_libksba_readline_zlib_openssl@1.1.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
sdancer@192 ~ % clear

sdancer@192 ~ % \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   194  100   194    0     0    361      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   360
100 24532  100 24532    0     0  32152      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 32152
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/sdancer/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/sdancer/.mkshrc /Users/sdancer/.profile /Users/sdancer/.bashrc /Users/sdancer/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/sdancer/.profile /Users/sdancer/.bash_profile /Users/sdancer/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/sdancer/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12 (latest) (c) 2009-2020 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl@1.1.........There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install coreutils libyaml libksba readline zlib openssl@1.1',
please read /Users/sdancer/.rvm/log/1687864948_ruby-3.0.0/package_install_coreutils_libyaml_libksba_readline_zlib_openssl@1.1.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
sdancer@192 ~ % brew -v
Homebrew 4.0.25
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 7ea36b10e57; last commit 2023-06-27)
sdancer@192 ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here was the openssl package that is failed to install. I managed to install it manually following the steps I describe below.

1. Download the latest version from
   https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.1.1.tar.gz
2. Uncompress the file with double click and open the terminal. Find
   the created folder and `cd openssl-3.1.1`
3. Continue with `perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method no-zlib darwin64-x86_64-cc enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`
4. `make`
5. `make test` (optional) I passed all tests
6. `sudo make install MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.1_1/share/man MANSUFFIX=ssl`
7. `openssl version` (optional - verification). It should report **OpenSSL
   3.1.1 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023)**
8. `which -a openssl` (optional).
9. `brew link openssl@3`
10. `brew list` (optional) you should see the openssl@3 inside installed
    packages.